# How to sort alphanumeric by numbers in shell

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Input file has data:

```
abc90
cd 18
bc14de
100def
```

Output should be:

```
bc14de
cd 18
abc90
100def
```

Is there any `sort` command to sort only by the number embedded in the alphanumeric data?

I tried this but it doesn't work as I want:

```
# sort -g FileName
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{rec=$0; gsub(/[^[:digit:]]+/, "", rec); print rec, $0}' file
    | sort -nk1 | cut -d $'\t' -f2-
bc14de
cd 18
abc90
100def
```

- `awk` is used to add a first column in input with only numeric characters using `gsub`
- `sort -nk1` is used for sorting input numerically on first column
- `cut` is finally used to truncate first column

Comment: Thnq , but i am new to usage of awk , is there any simple commands

Comment: You can always learn it. Anyway without awk you can use: `paste <(sed 's/[^[:digit:]]*//g' file) file | sort -nk1 | cut -d $'\t' -f2-`